# Cloud Communications - Using msgraph-sdk-java to call a Teams User in Android

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-cloudcommunications

As per title, Im trying to use the Microsoft Graph API to establish an Audio call to a Teams user.

The documentation seems a little lacklustre, but I've pieced everything together as well as I can.

Using ClientCredentialProvider with a registered Azure AD App, appropriate permissions applied. I'm able to collect a list of users, so I know I can authenticate to Graph API.

I don't know what the callbackUri should be in all honesty when defining a call, I've tried both myapp://xyz.domain.app and I've tried setting up a Bot and using that url as the call back.

When we post a call, we get back error code 9999 Unkown internal Server error.

If we dig deeper into where the post is made, we just get back error 500, Internal Server Error, with very little indication of what the error actually is.

Documentation elsewhere, such as the GroupCallBot https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/StatelessSamples/GroupCallBot suggests we need to setup a Bot? Done this, and still no joy.

First off, is calling a Teams User using the Microsoft Graph API and Cloud Communications supported? I've seen people give advice on it, so assume it would be. Is it supported in the msgraph-sdk-java? I did ask the question on Github but they closed the issue and neglected to tell me?

If it is supported, how can I dig deeper to find out why we're unable to establish a call?

Comment: Yes, Calling and meeting bots are supported in Teams. Could you please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/calls-meetings-bots-overview).  Please check this docs for [microsoftgraph SDK](https://microsoftgraph.github.io/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/docs/articles/index.html#graph-calling-sdk-and-stateful-client-builder).

Comment: Thanks Nikitha. Who can we reach out to to get this setup properly? As far as Im aware we've got the bot and the app setup but, we cannot find why we're getting this error and/or what is wrong in the setup.

Comment: Could you please drop a mail to microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com with brief description of the issue.

Comment: Hi there, have you got any success in making call from your Android app using ms graph sdk

Comment: Unfortunately no success at all.